# TFS Alert when label is created

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, tfsbuild

Can I configure an alert when a TFS Label is created ? I don't find that option in the current predefined alerts. These are the ones I found:

[image: Default Alerts]

And I want when a label is created:

[image: Label Created]

Send an email notification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible using the standard Alert features.

Comment: @nerlijma What are you using labels for, and why do you want to be alerted when they're created?

Comment: I use labels to create versions of the software. I work with Software Providers that access the TFS to work within an specific software development. When they complete a feature, all the code is checked in and they create a new label with the new version. I want to be notified when the provided has uploaded the whole code and labeled it. For instance, to develop a feature for Soft1, they will create a label. Main_Soft1_1.0.1. I want to receive an email that says, Label Main_Soft1_1.0.1 was created ....

Comment: As said, there is no such feature. You could ask them to associate to a work item and resolve that. Then put the alert on the work item.

Answer (score 0):

I created my own solution!  I don't know how much access you have to your on-premise TFS instance, but you need to be able to execute t-sql scripts against the TFS mssql database.  My solution is here:  https://github.com/Antebios/tfs-label-notification

And when anyone creates a TFSVC label I get an email alert that looks like this:

[image]

Basically, I created a database trigger to populate a table.  I query that table and send an email out, then mark the label as sent.  I also have a trigger to delete form that table just in case the label gets deleted.  I wrote the service in .NET Core just in case anyone wants to convert it to run within a container.  Let me know if this helps or not.